# What to do if null exception occur in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

See ,I have drop down control and i have keep the LIST as datasource. But if list is null Then it throw null exception. So what is the standard way to handle this situation?

Comment: Well, the answer is not handling it, is avoiding it.

Comment: Right. If you get this exception then *you have a bug*. Fix the bug, never handle the exception.

Comment: as eric said, never ever catch NullPointerException! if this occurs the app-flow (like webapp-request, gui-action) should crash. and no kidding... I have seen catching NPE code several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the list to the dropdown after checking whether the list is `null` or not.

```
if (list != null) {
   dd.DataSource = list;
}
else {
   dd.DataSource = new List<ObjType>();
}
```

**Note**: ObjType is the type of list items that you are using in the dropdown, for example `string`, if the list that you are using is a list of strings.

Thanks

Comment: Also, if using version 3.5 of the .NET Framework, the Enumerable.Empty<TResult>() method is ideal for creating an empty IEnumerable<T> instance.

Answer (score 4):

If you *can*, keep the list as an *empty list* rather than a *null list*. It's easy to confuse the usage of an empty list with a null list (what do each of these mean), and if you use empty lists consistently then you'll reduce the opportunity for null pointer exceptions.